# Can't edit the host file

Tags: windows-7, permissions, notepad++, file-permissions, permission-denied

I've been trying to edit my host file for a while now and I keep failing.
I tried to open notepad as administrator and then click **File --> Open** and choosing the host file but I get this error message:

**hosts**

**You don't have permission to open this file.**

**Contact the file owner or an administrator to obtain permission.**

I tried notepad++ as well (as administrator) but I couldn't even get to the file with it (it doesn't show the *etc* folder in *drivers*).
I also tried to check my "*User Account Control Settings*" but it was already on the lowest level (never notify).
While looking online for a solution I've noticed more people having the same problem but I couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Comment: Belongs to super-user, e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/372590/permissions-for-editing-hosts-file-on-windows-7-home-edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it! I had to right click the file, go to Properties, Security tab and click Edit.
Then I took ownership for the file and I had the ability to edit the file's permissions.

Comment: This is not wise in general, since footling about with the permissions on system files, which were specifically set to prevent problems from low-privileged users or malware, can have some unfortunate repercussions later.

Comment: If you take ownership, and it still won't allow editing, you can also take a copy of the file, edit it elsewhere and then copy it back to %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer, it's more a hack with security concerns.

Comment: @Marc Garcia this is what worked for me. Nothing else did, so I'm leaving the green check there. As for your security concerns, you can always go back and change the permissions back to their initial stage.

Comment: Somehow my hosts file attributes set itself to read only. Unchecking that solved the problem.

Answer (score 31):

You have to run notepad++ (or your favorite text editor) **as an administrator**. Right click notepad++ and it should display an option to run it as admin. Once open, locate the *hosts* file and open it with notepad++.

Windows *hosts* file location: `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`

**Note:** copy and paste the above url in the file-explorer when opening a file within notepad++ instead of locating it manually as some directories are hidden.

If the above doesn't work, Windows 10, 8 sometimes requires you to first [turn off your antivirus](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/disable-antivirus-software#1TC=windows-7).

---

If you require editing the hosts file often, you could look into third-party freeware  tools to aid you. [[1]](http://www.abelhadigital.com/hostsman)[[2]](https://hostsfileeditor.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I've already tried it. When clicking File --> Open and navigating to the "drivers" folder, I don't have the "etc" folder in the list.

Comment: @user2639433 copy and paste the above link to the host file in instead of locating it manually. Some files are hidden.

Comment: OK I did that but I still get the exact same error message when trying to open host with notepad++

Comment: this worked for me, and I was able to use regular Notepad, running it as administrator

Comment: For the hosts file in particular, this still doesn't work for me.  I can open the hosts file, but even with run as administrator, this file just won't edit.   I have what appears to be a read-only copy open.

Comment: @demongolem I think [this](http://superuser.com/questions/124888/how-can-i-modify-my-hosts-file-it-is-read-only-and-cannot-be-modified-even-as-a) will be of use.

Comment: I still had some issues. I had to start notepad++ as administrator. However, dragging the host file into notepad++ did NOT work. I had to use the notepad++ file menu to select to the file. Strange

Comment: The author said "I tried notepad++ as well (as administrator) but I couldn't even get to the file with it".

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz hence the note.

Answer (score 5):

This works:
For **Windows 7 and Windows Vista**

Click **Start -> All Programs -> Accessories.** 
**Right click** on Notepad and select **Run as administrator**. 
Click **Continue** on the "Windows needs your permission" UAC window. 
When Notepad opens Click **File -> Open**. 
In the filename field type the file location, i.e.:

> C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

Click **Open**. 
Make the necessary changes to the hosts file. 
Click **File -> Save** to save your changes.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I could open the file (and Notepad++ was running as admin) however I could not edit it: I could neither type some text, nor delete anything - no popups, no warnings - it looked like keyboard is not working.

I copied the hosts file in the same location, deleted the original hosts file and renamed the new one to hosts. After that I was able to edit the file. I am guessing this should be some permission issue.

OS - windows 7

Comment: This is pretty much the same symptoms and same outcome that I faced.  What I could not do in Notepad++ I could do in Notepad in administrator and save as mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

But first of all you have to do temporally disable your virus guard.

Answer (score 4):

Dissable your antivirus and open notepad.exe with run as administrator edit your host file and save this.

Answer (score 3):

'Run as admin' not enough in windows 8. Set 'modify' access also not enough if you have antivirus

So you need

1) Disable antivirus

2) Set 'modify' access for all applications

3) Modify 'hosts' file

4) Revert 1-2 steps

Answer (score 0):

On windows 8 running notepad as administrator wasn't enough for me to edit this file.  When I tried to open the file from within an administrator session of notepad the etc directory was empty.  I changing explorer to show hidden files and extensions, but that only helped in explorer.  To edit this with notepad I needed to modify the security settings on the file so that all users and all applications could write to the file.  After I finished my changes I set the file back to read only and execute for all applications and users.

Answer (score 0):

there are two notepad.exe in x64 windows,

you must use full path c:\windows\system2\notepad.exe ,this one is 64 bit version,

only type notepad whithout path may be launch 32 bit notepad.
(c:\windows\syswow64\notepad.exe)

"Run as administrator" just let you enforce launch 64 bit notepad.exe

using 32 bit software to edit c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

the x64 system will automatic redirect to c:\windows\syswow64\drivers\etc

and there is no hosts file.

the GUI stiil display current folder is c:\windows\system32

but the real folder is c:\windows\syswow64

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After opening the notepad as an Administrator and editing *hosts* file, I could not save it (denied access). I could not even change file's permissions. What worked for me was copying the file elsewhere, editing there, and then overwriting the original through Command Prompt opened as Administrator. I didn't have to turn off antivirus program.

To open the Command Prompt as administrator, press windows+X and select that option from the menu.

Than, type: `mv path-to-the-copy-of-hosts-file\hosts c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to uncheck "read only" property to allow modify that file.